# FreePBX - Notify missed calls on queue

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

I'm trying to configure the FreePBX queue to notify calls canceled by the calling party before answering.

I tried to lookup this in CDR, in logs and even in SIP trace but i didn't find anything useful.

There is an option for queue called "mark calls answered elswhere" but this function is not supported by all user agents and even if is, it marks call answered even if was not answered by anyone.

Is there any possible way to detect that the calling party hang up while waiting on the queue before his call was answered by anyone?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have lookup queue_log file.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Queue+Logs

CDR file is usless, becuase it also note alot of call attempt,so it is hard to manage queue only cdrs.

There are no any option like that for freepbx, but you can develop your own module or ask some expert create module for you.